# JSON - Setting field value inside all array elements

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have a JSON like the below one.

> store.book[*].author[*].share

I need to update the share value with (current value+10).
If share value is 9.2, then the updated value should be (19.2).  The new value can be a complex logic also. So, basically get the current value and update the new value based on the logic.

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95,
                "author": [
                 {
                   "name": "Mike Waugh",
                   "share": "9.2"
                 },
                 {
                   "name": "Shane Warne",
                   "share": "8.2"
                 }
                ]
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 9.0,
                "author": [
                 {
                   "name": "Steve Bro",
                   "share": "9.6"
                 },
                 {
                   "name": "Mikky waugh",
                   "share": "9.7"
                 }
               ]
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99,
                 "author": [
                 {
                   "name": "Evelyn Dough",
                   "share": "6.6"
                 },
                 {
                   "name": "Mark waugh",
                   "share": "5.7"
                 }
               ]
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I have an answer to update for a single element.

```
DocumentContext json = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(jsonInput);
String jayPath = "$..book[0].author[0].share";
String tagValue = "10"+json.get(jayPath);
System.out.println(json.set(jayPath, tagValue).jsonString());
```

Any way to update for all the shares with the new value based on the logic.

Confused with for loop also.

```
$..book[*]  ---> get length

for each,
$..book[0].author[*]  ------> length

for each
$..book[0].author[0].share
$..book[0].author[1].share
```

Is there any other better way?